# New Picturebox in a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#

Hey there!
The origin of my problem is a form with a tablelayoutpanel - which as we I know only allows one element per cell. 
Now one cell contains a resizing textbox. On top of this textbox I will have to place a few pictureboxes (just some pics in the text - and there is no possibility to place them as real pics in a richtextbox).
Now although the concept of a tablelayoutpanel allows only one element per cell I was thinking maybe after the form is painted it would be possible to place another element above - just by creating a picbox right from code:

```
 PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
 pb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49,49);
 pb.Location = new Point(20,20);
 this.controls.Add(pb);
```

Now this isn't working.....any ideas how to bypass this problem?
thanks for any help!!!!!

Greetings,

Lorenz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your picture box is at the bottom of the Z-order, covered by other controls.  Add this line:

```
pb.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Damn! I tried around with god damn TabIndex property for ages and then there's a simple function doing all the work^^

Answer (score 1):

Put a `Panel` in the cell, and add the controls to the `Panel` instead. That way the cell will contain only one control, but you can still use both the text box and the picture box within the panel.

Comment: Thanks also for the fast answer that was of course the first thing I tried - but it didn't work - sorry I should've pointed that out in the question - what I needed was the aboce function to get past all that TabIndex-stuff :)